# Passing form data from .HTML to .ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, multipartform-data

So I was trying to create a simple ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), the **Web Forms** variant. So in my application, I have these three files: `pizza_builder.html`, which **POST**s data to `ProcessPizza.aspx`, which has its code-behind defined in `ProcessPizza.aspx.cs`. Now when I try to access the form data from the `Request` object, I get null values. In fact, it doesn't even use the right request method; `GET` is used instead. Have a look at my codes below and let me know if you can spot the problem or if I should add more information.

**What I want to achieved:** When a user submits the form in `pizza_builder.html`, I want the `Page_Load` handler for `ProcessPizza.aspx.cs` to retrieve the form data manipulate it and send it to the ASPX view for display.
TIA.

**pizza_builder.html:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="card col-7">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="h4 text-center">Order details</h3>
                        <form action="ProcessPizza.aspx" method="POST">
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="fullName" class="form-label">Full name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" name="fullName" required>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="phoneNumber" class="form-label">Phone number</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" required>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="deliveryOption" class="form-label">Delivery Option</label>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="deliveryOption" id="deliveryOption1" value="Delivery" required>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="deliveryOption1">
                                            Delivery
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="deliveryOption" id="deliveryOption2" value="Pickup">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="deliveryOption2">
                                            Pickup
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h6>Pizza details</h6>
                            <div><hr class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="size" class="form-label">Size</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="size" name="size" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Not selected</option>
                                        <option value="Small:2">Small $2</option>
                                        <option value="Medium:4">Medium $4</option>
                                        <option value="Large:6">Large $6</option>
                                        <option value="Extra Large:7">Extra Large $7</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="crust" class="form-label">Crust</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="crust" name="crust" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Not selected</option>
                                        <option value="Regular:0">Regular $0</option>
                                        <option value="Stuffed:2">Stuffed $2</option>
                                        <option value="Deep Dish:4">Deep Dish $4</option>
                                        <option value="Thin:3">Thin $3</option>
                                        <option value="Cheesy Garlic Butter:4">Cheesy Garlic Butter $4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="sauce" class="form-label">Sauce</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="sauce" name="sauce" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Not selected</option>
                                        <option value="Tomato:1">Tomato $1</option>
                                        <option value="Pesto:2">Pesto $2</option>
                                        <option value="Creamy Alfredo:3">Creamy Alfredo $3</option>
                                        <option value="Chocolate:3">Chocolate $3</option>
                                        <option value="No Sauce:0">No Sauce $0</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="toppings" class="form-label">Toppings</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni:1" id="toppings1" name="toppings">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="toppings1">
                                                    Pepperoni $1
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Sausage:2" id="toppings2" name="toppings">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="toppings2">
                                                    Sausage $2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Bacon:2" id="toppings3" name="toppings">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="toppings3">
                                                    Bacon $2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Ham:3" id="toppings4" name="toppings">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="toppings4">
                                                    Ham $3
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Onions:1" id="toppings5" name="toppings">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="toppings5">
                                                    Onions $1
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="premiumAdditions" class="form-label">Premimum Additions</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Extra Cheese:2" id="premiumAdditions1" name="premiumAdditions">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="premiumAdditions1">
                                                    Extra Cheese $2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Extra Meat:3" id="premiumAdditions2" name="premiumAdditions">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="premiumAdditions2">
                                                    Extra Meat $3
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Egg Bake:2" id="premiumAdditions3" name="premiumAdditions">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="premiumAdditions3">
                                                    Egg Bake $2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Gluten Free:1" id="premiumAdditions4" name="premiumAdditions">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="premiumAdditions4">
                                                    Gluten Free $1
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Flavored Crust:2" id="premiumAdditions5" name="premiumAdditions">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="premiumAdditions5">
                                                    Flavored Crust $2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h6>Meal options</h6>
                            <div><hr class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="soda" class="form-label">Soda (2Ltr)</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="soda" id="soda1" value="Coke:1">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="soda1">
                                                    Coke $1
                                                </label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="soda" id="soda2" value="Pepsi:2">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="soda2">
                                                    Pepsi $2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="soda" id="soda3" value="Dr. Pepper:2">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="soda3">
                                                    Dr. Pepper $2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="soda" id="soda4" value="Ginger Ale:3">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="soda4">
                                                    Ginger Ale $3
                                                </label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="soda" id="soda5" value="Monster:2">
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="soda5">
                                                    Monster $2
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="side" class="form-label">Side</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="side" name="side">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Not selected</option>
                                        <option value="Cesar Salad:2">Cesar Salad $2</option>
                                        <option value="Fries:3">Fries $3</option>
                                        <option value="Wings:3">Wings $3</option>
                                        <option value="Ratatouille:4">Ratatouille $4</option>
                                        <option value="Potato Salad:2">Potato Salad $2</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row justify-content-end mb-3">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <label for="tip" class="form-label">Tip (Optional)</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tip" id="tip" min="0">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Order</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

**ProcessPizza.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProcessPizza.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pizza.ProcessPizza" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Pizza" %>
    
    ... 

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="card col-7">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="h4 text-center">Order details</h3>

                        <h6>Customer details</h6>
                        <div>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </div>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Name: <span class="fw-bolder text-capitalize"><%= fullName %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Phone: <span class="fw-bolder"><%= phoneNumber %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Address: <span class="fw-bolder"><%= address %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Delivery method: <span class="fw-bolder"><%= deliveryOption %></span>
                        </p>

                        <h6 class="mt-3">Pizza details</h6>
                        <div>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </div>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Size: <span class="fw-bolder"><%# sizeItm.GetName()  %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Crust: <span class="fw-bolder"><%# crustItm.GetName() %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Sauce: <span class="fw-bolder"><%# sauceItm.GetName() %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Toppings: <span class="fw-bolder">
                                <% if (toppingItms != null)
                                    {
                                        Response.Write(Item.JoinItems(toppingItms));
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Response.Write("<span>None</span>");
                                    }
                                %>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Premium Additions: <span class="fw-bolder">
                                <% if (premiumAdditionItms != null)
                                    {
                                        Response.Write(Item.JoinItems(premiumAdditionItms));
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Response.Write("<span>None</span>");
                                    }
                                %>
                            </span>
                        </p>

                        <%if (sodaItm != null || sideItm != null)
                            { %>
                        <h6 class="mt-3">Meal option details</h6>
                        <div>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </div>
                        <%if (sodaItm != null)
                            {%>

                        <p class="m-0">
                            Soda: <span class="fw-bolder"><%# sodaItm.GetName() + " $" + sodaItm.GetPrice()%></span>
                        </p>
                        <%} %>

                        <%if (sideItm != null)
                            { %>
                        <p class="m-0">
                            Side: <span class="fw-bolder"><%# sideItm.GetName() + " $" + sideItm.GetPrice() %></span>
                        </p>
                        <%} %>
                        <%} %>

                        <%--Totals--%>
                        <h6 class="mt-3">Totals</h6>
                        <div>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </div>
                        <p class="m-0 h5">
                            Total: <span class="fw-bolder"><%= total %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0 h5">
                            Tax: <span class="fw-bolder"><%= tax %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0 h5">
                            Tip: <span class="fw-bolder"><%= tip %></span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="m-0 h5 text-primary">
                            Grand Total: <span class="fw-bolder"><%= grandTotal %></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

**ProcessPizza.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Pizza
{
    public partial class ProcessPizza : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected Item sodaItm { get; set; }
        protected Item sideItm { get; set; }
        protected List<Item> toppingItms { get; set; }
        protected List<Item> premiumAdditionItms { get; set; }

        protected string fullName { get; set; }
        protected string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        protected string address { get; set; }
        protected string deliveryOption { get; set; }
        protected Item sizeItm { get; set; }
        protected Item crustItm { get; set; }
        protected Item sauceItm { get; set; }
        protected double total { get; set; }
        protected double tax { get; set; }
        protected double tip { get; set; }
        protected double grandTotal { get; set; }
        protected string requestError { get; set; }

        private const double TAX_RATE = 1.11;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
            {
                fullName = Request.Form["fullName"];
                phoneNumber = Request.Form["phoneNumber"];
                address = Request.Form["address"];
                deliveryOption = Request.Form["deliveryOption"];

                string size = Request.Form["size"];
                sizeItm = Item.Create(size);
                /*ViewData["size"] = sizeItm.GetName() + " $" + sizeItm.GetPrice();*/
                string crust = Request.Form["crust"];
                crustItm = Item.Create(crust);
                /*ViewData["crust"] = crustItm.GetName() + " $" + crustItm.GetPrice();*/
                string sauce = Request.Form["sauce"];
                sauceItm = Item.Create(sauce);
                /*ViewData["sauce"] = sauceItm.GetName() + " $" + sauceItm.GetPrice();*/

                // start total calculation
                total = sizeItm.GetPrice() + crustItm.GetPrice() + sauceItm.GetPrice();

                string[] toppings = Request.Form.GetValues("toppings");
                toppingItms = new List<Item>();
                if (toppings != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in toppings)
                    {
                        toppingItms.Add(Item.Create(item));
                    }

                    total += SumList(toppingItms);
                }

                string[] premiumAdditions = Request.Form.GetValues("premiumAdditions");
                premiumAdditionItms = new List<Item>();
                if (premiumAdditions != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in premiumAdditions)
                    {
                        premiumAdditionItms.Add(Item.Create(item));
                    }

                    total += SumList(premiumAdditionItms);
                }

                string soda = Request.Form["soda"];
                sodaItm = null;
                if (soda != null)
                {
                    sodaItm = Item.Create(soda);
                    total += sodaItm.GetPrice();
                }

                string side = Request.Form["side"];
                sideItm = null;
                if (side != null)
                {
                    sideItm = Item.Create(side);
                    total += sideItm.GetPrice();
                }

                string tipStr = Request.Form["tip"];
                tip = 0.0;

                try
                {
                    tip = Item.ParseDouble(tipStr);
                }
                catch
                {
                    requestError = "Cannot convert '" + tipStr + "' to double. Ensure to use numerics";
                }

                tax = TAX_RATE * total;
                grandTotal = total + tax + tip;

                DataBind();
            }
        }

        private double SumList(List<Item> list)
        {
            double total = 0;

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                total += item.GetPrice();
            }

            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a WebForms guy, it's 2023, it's time to leave WebFroms behind, there are much better  asp.net options these days

Comment: Do a little debugging with the help of the network tab in browser tools. Check that the request is sent via POST from your HTML page. Then set a breakpoint in you C# and  check the `Request`  object. If you are going to use WebForms , use WebForms as intended, your actual form should be part of that ASPX page, not a separate HTML page. Also limit the amount of `<%  = %>` and use actual WebControls instead, setting the values server side.

Comment: @JonP, I'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: You are using WebForms like Classic ASP. WebForms has its own layer: it doesn't use "if Request method == POST" or <% in ASPX. You can use them but WebForms is not built in this way.

Comment: Besides all the facts mentioned in the comments, which are strongly better to consider them, it seems this code should work as it is. If request.httpmethod is GET and request. form values are null, it means either the form method in html page is GET (which according to code is not) or the processpizza page is loaded directly.

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh, yeah it seems the ProcessPizza.aspx is loaded directly. Haven't figured a way to work around this as it also seems like an anti-pattern and no one seems to know why it's happening. I have decided to go fully with Razor-powered templates. I just wanted this cause the client kept insisting they want to see .aspx on the URL :D :D

Comment: Good luck with the client. Please also check this: put `response.write($"<p>referrer={request.urlreferrer})</p>");` at top of page-load to ensure if it is really come from pizza_builder. If it is not, replace that with : `if (request.urlreferrer == null) { response. Redirect("pizza_builder.html"); }` . Atleast, it will be clear the problem is not the design.